# How to represent the groups symbolically?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

What will be the group if the groups given by following descriptions were represented using symbols/notation (like $Z_p$ etc.)

1). Cyclic group of order $p^2 q$.

2). Semidirect product of cyclic group of order $q$ by a cyclic group of order $p^2$, where the action  by conjugation of a generator is an automorphism of order $p$.

3). Semidirect product of cyclic group of order $q$ by a cyclic group of order $p^2$, where the action  by conjugation of a generator is an automorphism of order $p^2$.

4). Semidirect product of cyclic group of order $pq$ by a cyclic group of order $p$, where the action  by conjugation of a generator is an automorphism of order $p$.

5). Direct product of cyclic group of order $p$ and cyclic group of order $pq$, which is also same as direct product of elementary abelian group of order $p^2$ and cyclic group of order $q$.

Please help me with this question.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Well, did you look at your course notes and tried to figure things out?

Comment: Yes, but can you please give the answer of this? Its bit difficult..

Comment: 1). $Z/p^2q Z$ and 5). $Z/pZ$ X $Z/pqZ$ which is same as $Z/p^2Z$ X $Z/qZ$

Comment: And some authors prefer the notation $C_q$ or $\mathbb{Z}_q=\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ for the cyclic group of order $q$. For example the first question has the answer $C_{p^2q}$.

Comment: The direct product uses the symbol $\times$ (\times) which is not the letter $\mathsf{X}$ (\mathsf{X})

Comment: For semidirect products you use the symbol $\rtimes$ (\rtimes)

Answer (score 0):

Cyclic groups of order $n$ are often denoted multiplicatively by $C_n$. For $n=p,p^2,p^2q$ and so on we write $C_p,C_{p^2},C_{p^2q}$. The semidirect product then is denoted by
$$
C_q\rtimes_{\theta}C_{p^2}.
$$
Here the automorphism is denoted by $\theta$.